# UIButton touchUpInside action firing multiple times per click

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have three buttons set up in Interface Builder, each tied via touchUpInside to btnSelection:

```
- (IBAction)btnSelection:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"tag: %i", [sender tag]);
}
```

In my console, the first click registers correctly (after a second or so delay, which seems a bit weird) but any subsequent touch of any of the 3 buttons results in first logging the previous tag value, then logging the new tag.

Touch #1 (btn w/ tag=0):

tag:0

Touch #2 (btn w/ tag=1):

tag:0
tag:1

Touch #3 (btn w/ tag=2):

tag:1
tag:2

and so on.

I can't figure out why two events are being logged each time (with the first being the previously touched button.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason is that if you hooked up your button to the event, and then copied that button and hooked up the event again, you might be calling your `btnSelection` function twice.

In interface builder, check to see that you only have one callback to `btnSelection`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I definitely only have one callback to btnSelection for each button. The buttons are distinct, and were created individually, so they shouldn't (and by all accounts don't) have any left over callbacks from being duplicated from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in your callback and see where the call is coming from.  What you describe works great in 100s of 1000s of apps -- you're calling your routine 2x, somehow.

(No offense, but it's your code.  :)

Comment: In my case, it was my code, I was wiring up to the event every time I had set a property value. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was not included in the question but in the case that you might have a uibutton in a custom uitableviewcell, make sure not to mess with selection settings when setting up your cells for reuse. (Messing with cells being set up for reuse can make all subviews in the cell go weird and make things pile up or make things like buttons appear to toggle when they are really reloading cells) Mess with those kinds of things when first customizing your cell format or after your cells are made

Answer (score 0):

This is quite likely related to a mistake you have made in Interface Builder. I have seen this happen when for example a button in a view is clicked but the next view has some problem like a broken IBOutlet connect from when you copied and pasted some IB objects. Breakpointing the item would result in 3 calls to IBAction and then death.